# Hibernate persistance

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am very new to Hibernate and am trying to teach myself by taking a course online. I have few questions, please see the code below:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/"}, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RootServlet.class);


@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    logger.info("init started");
    // Read the data from a file
    String url = ReadProperties.readProperty("data");

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        logger.info("parsing data");
        JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createParser(buffer.toString());
        if (JsonToken.START_ARRAY != parser.nextToken()) {
            throw new Exception("bad token");
        }

        JsonToken token = parser.nextToken();
        while(token == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {

            Employee emp = new Employee();

            emp.setFName(parser.nextTextValue());
            emp.setLName(parser.nextTextValue());

            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            try {
                 session.beginTransaction();
                 session.persist(e);        
                 session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {

            }
            session.close();

            token = parser.nextToken();

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    }      
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Employee> list = session.createCriteria(Employee.class).list();

    for (Employee e : list) {
        response.getWriter().println("First Name " + entity.getFName());
        response.getWriter().println("Last Name " + e.getLName());
    }

}
```

}

Hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class,hbm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
    <mapping class="com.waracle.cakemgr.beans.CakeEntity"></mapping>        
</session-factory>
```

I don't have a database setup, I have just given dummy values in the hibernate config file, but the above code when run, reads from the file, appears as if the data is getting persistent and doGet method also displays the list of employees.
I don't understand why this is working, will the  session.persist not throw any errors? Also, if I add another page with same code, on traversing to that page from this leads to waiting for session.persist to finish endlessly.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a in-memory database: `HSQLDB`.

`<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>` indicates that use the in-memory database, instead of any physical database.